# Unable to parse JSON response body in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, http

I am trying to parse the below response body that I received from my http request.

```
callback({"processingDurationMillis":29,"authorisedAPI":true,"success":true,"airline":null,"errorMessage":null,"distance":"4,128.4","units":"km"})
```

I need help in accessing the `distance` field in the body, but first I am unable to change this JSON into a JS object.

Here's what I'm doing

```
response = HTTP.call('GET', URL,function(err,result){
        console.log(result.content);
        data = JSON.parse(result.content);

        var extractedData = data['distanceResponse'];
        console.log(extractedData);
    });
```

I'm able to log `result.content` but nothing after. Please help?
Thanks much appreciated!

Comment: The data returned in a function with a JSON property in the form of `JSONP`. You need a handler for `callback()`

Comment: Thanks @CarlK, but what do I implement in this handler inside the callback?

Comment: Usually a JSONP API is handled by just adding a `<script>` tag to the page with the source set to the URL. You also create a global callback function, and it should just handle the object (won't be JSON; it'll be a ready-to-use JavaScript object) however you want.